# How do I interrupt a long running Java Thread in a ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Here is my situation:

I have a `ThreadPoolExecutor` on whose `Thread`s I make a HTTP call to a server via SSL. Sometimes, I get a `NullPointerException` because the client cannot decrypt the server response and the thread just hangs there indefinitely causing a livelock in the pool. Does anybody know a good way to target a specific thread in the pool, check how long it's been running and kill/interrupt it if it's been running for longer than say 3 minutes?

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: My suggestion would be to fix the NullPointerException. Such an exception is a clear sign of a bug. It should not happen. And even if it happens, it should just abort the task. For more help, as always, post the code and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: The exception comes from this library https://java.net/projects/http-client Yes I know it is/might be a bug, but I will end up migrating my project to Java 9 anyway and that has a HTTP client (probably the same) baked in. I would like to deal with reporting bugs then. Right now I have to get things done in a pinch. Besides, I would like to have control over my threads anyway, just in case.

Comment: I might be missing something, but if you get an NPE from that library, the control is back to your code already, why can't you just do a cleanup ( if any ) and exit the run block ?

Comment: Can you paste some code? Why don't you do something when you get the NPE?

Comment: I would but the code is spread over some classes and I don't think I have room here for that. The basic idea is that the SSL encryption and decryption is done in a parallel on a `ExecutorService` which sometimes allows a NPE to fall through and that thread just exits execution. My thread that I start the process on does not have knowledge of the other thread dying and it just keeps waiting on a result that never comes. That's why I want to time the wait.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep a reference to that thread, then you can call interrupt() method on it in order to interrupt it. for example:

```
Thread t = new Theard(r);
t.interrupt();
```

(r is runnable, a job)

With Spring aop you can count the time passed from the moment that start method was triggered.

Another solution is to use your own thread factory, in the factory make sure to interrupt each thread after 3 minutes.

Another approach is to use: ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

set your task to run for a period of time, **and let it end gracefully after one execution**.

Comment: I am already extending ThreadPoolExecutor and overriding the before/afterExecute methods but it feels hacky and coupled. I was hoping someone would have a more elegant solution

Comment: with thread factory, you can add a timer of 3 minutes which afterward interrupt the thread.

Comment: Yes but in `ThreadFactory` I can only set the time when the `Thread` is created. I need to set the time when each task starts.

Comment: Yes I did. However I want to leave all that functionality to the `ExecutorService` and only kill the thread if I have to. I am playing with a scenario right now that involves a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` that schedules a task periodically and inspects threads. It's hacky though...